# Ansible Jinja split on backslash fails

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I have a ansible play that tries to split a string in the format of `domain\user` into its parts:

This is the task

```
tasks:
    - name: do something which requires domain and user
      win_shell: echo "{{ lookup('aws_ssm', 'service_user-account-2921', decrypt=True, region='eu-central-1' )}}.split('\\')[0] }}"
```

This results in:

```
ERROR! failed at splitting arguments, either an unbalanced jinja2 block or quotes: {{'DOMAIN\USER'.split('\')[0]}}
```

if I change the task to remove the lookup it still fails as long as I use `\` as delimiter

```
      #win_shell: echo "{{ 'test,strings'.split(',')[0] }}" #WORKS
      win_shell: echo "{{ 'DOMAIN\\USER'.split('\\')[0]}}" #FAILS
```

how to split on a backslash in ansible / jinja?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Q: ***"How to split on a backslash in ansible/jinja?"***

A: Put the separator into a variable. For example

```yaml
      vars:

        separator: '\'
        text: 'domain\user'

      tasks:

        - debug:
            msg: "{{ text.split(separator) }}"
```

gives

```yaml
    msg:
    - domain
    - user
```